# Handling data-loading within a child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component called `Dashboard`. This component itself houses several *chart* components e.g. Bar, Pie, Radial etc. I load all the data within the `Dashboard` component with `useEffect` and then send the required data to the individual chart components.

```
// dashboard.js

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
...
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch 'data' here...
  setData(data)
})
...
<div>
  <PieChart pieData={data[0]}/>
  <BarChart barData={data[1]} />
</div>
```

The problem is that within the child component i.e. `<PieChart />` or `<BarChart />`, the data often loads after a while and unless I check for the data being present, the charts start breaking.

```
// pieChart.js

const PieChart = props => {

// This is the problem
const data = props.pieData && props.pieData.current && props.pieData.current[0] 

// ...render chart here
}
```

I have to extract the exact info from props to render the chart because of the nature of the data I am receiving. And unless I do checks  - `&&`, the chart breaks because the parent component has not sent the data to the child yet.

Is there any better way to achieve this, like using `try`, `catch`, `finally`?

Comment: What do you mean by break? the pie component doesn't rerender? can you add more code exaple of your pie component?

Comment: If I just do `const data = props.pieData.current[0]`, the chart breaks because `props.pieData.current[0]` does not exist yet because `props.pieData.current` does not exist yet because `props.pieData` does not exist yet because it hasn't been loaded and sent from the parent component yet. That's why I use `&&` to check existence.

Comment: You can use optional chaining which is on the latest create react app version or lodash get.It seems that props.pieData is sufficient to that data isn't there yet.